# How to continuously update drawing in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, asynchronous, uiview

I am continuously reading data (CGFloat array) from a source, and I want to draw a line on a UIView from the data points on that source.

I understand that I need to use UIBezierPath to create the line. I am able to do so initially, but I do not know how to keep on updating the drawing on the UIView [like a series of path.move(..)].

Does anyone know how to implement this?

TIA

Comment: A few thoughts. First, since you wish to update the UI, you need the main thread to do that. Next, can you explain what *"continuously reading data"* means? Some code on that CGFloat array would help. Last, you may end up fudging things - as in making "look" like it's continuously updating. The quickest way to do that is (1) read *all* your data in the array while (2) providing the user with some feedback, then (3) building your Bezier path followed by (4) animating drawing it.

Comment: @dfd I will be getting the floats from a mic feed, and I want to plot/draw those points in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-class UIView and override the `draw` rect method:

```
import UIKit

class MyLineView: UIView {
    // Edit:add the data to draw
    public var lineData : Array<Float>?

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Read the values and draw the lines
        // using your bezier functions

        // Edit: just to test - you can see the new data
        if let data = lineData {
            print("Redrawing \(data.count) elements")
        }
    }
}
```

In your view controller create a property of type `Timer` and start it going at an appropriate point with your desired frame rate:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var animationTimer : Timer?
    var myLineView : MyLineView?
    **// Edit: add an array of data**
    var myData : Array<Float>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myLineView = MyLineView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.view.addSubview(myLineView!)
        // Edit: init data
        self.myData = Array()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // Update the view at roughly 10Hz
        animationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            //Edit: example update of the data before redrawing
            self.myData?.append(Float(1))
            self.myLineView!.lineData = self.myData!

            self.myLineView!.setNeedsDisplay()
        })
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        // Stop updating
        animationTimer!.invalidate()
        animationTimer = nil
    }
}
```

This will call drawRect on your subclass at an approximate rate of 10Hz.

Comment: I see that you call setNeedDisplay(), but how am I going to manipulate my bezier paths inside the custom UIView?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show transferring the data to the view. Using the code you're already using to draw the initial line, just extend that to re-draw the entire data set every frame.

Comment: Marked as answer because `self.myLineView!.lineData = self.myData!` helped me. My data pull is on another thread so I had to put `self.myLineView!.setNeedsDisplay()` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`. Thanks!

Comment: What are these overrides called in newer versions of Swift?